# в одной координатной сетке постройте 2 гистограммы распределения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

пытаюсь нарисовать две гистограммы распределения по существующему датафрейму, который приложу в виде скриншота. (уже с необходимыми условиями)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PBLS1

```
        Year    Global_Sales
15      2010.0  21.82
9183    2010.0  0.14
8300    2010.0  0.17
8031    2010.0  0.18
13312   2010.0  0.05
1442    2010.0  1.35
1339    2010.0  1.44
1121    2010.0  1.64
1820    2010.0  1.12
192     2010.0  5.13
62      2010.0  9.88
139     2010.0  6.24
14619   2011.0  0.03
4770    2011.0  0.41
5222    2011.0  0.36
228     2011.0  4.64
5698    2011.0  0.32
140     2011.0  6.24
669     2011.0  2.36
658     2011.0  2.38
12360   2011.0  0.06
632     2011.0  2.44
830     2011.0  2.04
6041    2012.0  0.29
13157   2012.0  0.05
2489    2012.0  0.83
65      2012.0  9.76
3374    2012.0  0.60
843     2012.0  2.02
970     2012.0  1.78
12333   2013.0  0.06
10741   2013.0  0.10
748     2013.0  2.18
72      2013.0  9.20
1208    2013.0  1.54
1141    2013.0  1.61
5419    2013.0  0.34
1431    2013.0  1.36
1836    2014.0  1.11
643     2014.0  2.41
8233    2014.0  0.17
7975    2014.0  0.19
439     2014.0  3.15
4135    2014.0  0.48
3454    2014.0  0.58
1416    2014.0  1.37
2427    2014.0  0.85
7548    2015.0  0.20
260     2015.0  4.26
2729    2015.0  0.75
467     2015.0  3.00
1018    2015.0  1.74
4513    2016.0  0.43
3927    2016.0  0.51
10814   2016.0  0.10
5015    2016.0  0.38
```

```
PBLS2
         Year   Global_Sales
965     2010.0  1.80
804     2010.0  2.08
7879    2010.0  0.19
12166   2010.0  0.07
3928    2010.0  0.51
... ... ...
13702   2016.0  0.04
7564    2016.0  0.20
15801   2016.0  0.02
7180    2016.0  0.22
11550   2016.0  0.08
```

если рисовать по датафреймам, должен получиться требуемый результат.

есть итоговый результат, который сильно отличается от того, который получается у меня. итоговый результат тоже приложу. сама задача -

в одной координатной сетке постройте 2 гистограммы распределения мировых продаж игр издателей "microsoft game studios" и "take-two interactive" после 2010 года (включая 2010 год).

желаемый результат -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

прежде гистограммы не рисовал, попытался отрисовать так же, как рисуется линейный график, однако попал в облаву - по моему примеру по сетке x выводятся иные значения, нежели требуемые, по y выводится иное кол-во записей вместо существующих. прошу вашей скорой помощи с решением данной задачи и нахождением моих ошибок

моя примерная нерабочая задача -

```
pbls = df[df['Publisher'] == 'Microsoft Game Studios'][['Year', 'Global_Sales']][df['Year'] >= 2010].sort_values(by='Year')
pbls2 = df[df['Publisher'] == 'Take-Two Interactive'][['Year', 'Global_Sales']][df['Year'] >= 2010].sort_values(by='Year')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

#ax.hist([pbls['Global_Sales'], pbls2['Global_Sales']], len(pbls), alpha=0.5, label=['Microsoft Game Studios', 'Take-Two Interactive'])

ax.hist(pbls['Global_Sales'], len(pbls), label='Microsoft Game Studios')
ax.hist(pbls2['Global_Sales'], len(pbls2), label='Take-Two Interactive')

ax.set_title('мировые продажи издателей после 2010 года')
ax.set_xlabel('млн. продаж')
ax.set_ylabel('записей')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

где pbls - microsoft game studios, pbls2 - take-two соответственно

моя задача выполняется как -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

только со взгляда похоже на то, что требуется. еще раз прошу вашей поддержки в этом вопросе

спасибо заранее за все данные ответы в этой теме:)

Comment: Пожалуйста, данные для обработки приведите текстом, а не скринами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в операторах  `ax.hist(....)` вставить параметр `bins=10`

Comment: Это собственно второй параметр, вместо `len(pbls)` ему нужно написать 10